# AngularJS search list with text input, clicking a list item should update text box accordingly and hide list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I'm still getting to grips with AngularJS and haven't be able to find anything similar to my issue. Basically I'm filtering a list of station names with a text box and each of the list items gets displayed as a button.

When a user clicks a button it should update the text box with that value, as well as hide the list again. I have tried using 'ng-click' on the buttons and targeting the input boxes but cannot get this to work, although there is no error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, or suggestions if I'm going the wrong way about it completely. Many thanks :)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="txtSearch" placeholder="From" id="one">
    <ul>
      <li ng-if="txtSearch" ng-repeat="test in List1 | filter:txtSearch track by test.id">
      <button>{{ test.name }}</button>
      </li>
    </ul>

<hr>

    <input type="text" ng-model="txtSearch2" ng-change="CallSearch(txtSearch2)" placeholder="To">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="test in List2 track by test.id">
      <button>{{ test.name }}</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.List1 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Uxbridge'},
    {id: 2, name: 'West Drayton'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Hayes'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Hillingdon'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Ealing'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Southall'},
    {id: 7, name: 'Harrow'},
    {id: 8, name: 'Eastcote'},
    {id: 9, name: 'Ruislip'},
    {id: 10, name: 'Hounslow'}
  ];

  $scope.CallSearch = function(textSearch) {console.log(textSearch.length);
    if (textSearch.length > 0) {
      $scope.List2 = $scope.List1.filter(function (item) {
        return Object.keys(item).some(function (key) {
          return angular.isString(item[key]) && item[key].toLowerCase().search(textSearch) !== -1
        });
      });
    }
    else {
      $scope.List2 = [];
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right at the first time: you should handle this logic by calling a function with `ng-click`

Your button could look like this:

```
<button ng-click="addStation(test)>{{test.name}}</button>"
```

And in your controller, your function could be like this:

```
function addStation(station) {
  $scope.txtSearch = station
  $scope.List2 = [] 
}
```